# FastAPI Path Parameter Validation with DB Query

Tags: python, rest, fastapi

I want to validate some path parameters with a db query. If the path parameter value does not exist in the db it would raise an HTTPException. I was hoping to introduce a middleware exception handler but the "scope" object does not include a "path_params" key. This makes sense since the middleware is processed before it hits the route function.

Currently I have come up with the following approach using Dependency Injection.

route function:

```
@router.get("/client/{client_id}", response_model=list[schemas.Payments])
async def get_payments_by_client(
    client: models.Client = Depends(get_client_by_id),
    db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)
):
    payments = crud.read_payments_by_client(client.id, db)
    if not db_payments:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="No payments found")

    return db_payments
```

service function:

```
def get_client_by_id(
    client_id: int,
    db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)
) -> models.Client:
    db_client = db.query(models.Client).filter(models.Client.id == client_id).first()
    if not db_client:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=404,
            detail="Client not found",
        )
    return db_client
```

Question 1:

What is the best approach for path parameter validation with db query in a RESTful API, and more specifically for a FastAPI app ?

Question 2:

Would the API execution time increase significantly with every path parameter being checked with a db query? Would caching help improve the execution time ?

Comment: It's perfectly fine; having "this route depends on a valid client" is a good dependency, it makes your controller functions easily composable and reusable. You would have to check this in some location regardless, so having it as a dependency will not affect execution time in any meaningful way; performance optimizations becomes relevant when you need them, not before - whatever the slowest part of your request cycle ends up being might not be what you think it's going to be. Optimize when necessary.